# package is in use and will not be installed

Tags: r

Using R x64 3.2.3 I get this message:

```
> install.packages("stringr")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/leews/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error: package ‘stringr’ is in use and will not be installed
```

what I have to do??

Comment: Just open a fresh session and try it again.

Answer (score 22):

Try

```
detach("package:stringr", unload = TRUE)
install.packages("stringr", dependencies=TRUE)
```