# InstallationWarning: package 'XYZ' is in use and will not be installed: R

Tags: r, build

I am trying to install package `SBCK` from R build using `Rscript build.R -c -v -i` in windows command prompt following the steps given [here](https://github.com/yrobink/SBCK). However, I ended up with package `SBCK` being not installed because of following error/warning `InstallationWarning: package 'SBCK' is in use and will not be installed`. I have no package with name `SBCK` installed on my system, so I do not understand why I am getting this warning message and thus not to be able to install the R package.

I know that similar question have been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721149/package-is-in-use-and-will-not-be-installed) but solution there does not work in my case.

I am using R version 4.2.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Once 'build.R' is run, "SBCK_0.5.0.tar.gz" is created in the 'SBCK-R' folder.
You can now install it via the package archive file option or pointing to that file in the install.packages command. I faced the same issue and this solved it.